# How do you get HK-51?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

How do I get HK-51? I'm level 55 and I want to get the two non-story companions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite a long answer, so I'll refer you to a guide. It is from [Dulfy](http://dulfy.net/2012/10/11/swtor-patch-1-5the-hunt-for-hk-51companion-droid/), and is very trustworthy. If I remember correctly, I used this guide too when I wanted the companion. Good luck!

This is a very quick list of what you have to do:

- Complete mission: Fatal Errors (Empire) | The Fatality (Republic)– Heroic 2+ (starts in Section X)
- Complete mission:Theoretika  (Heroic 2+) (available when completed previous quest. Travel to the unknown area in the galaxy with your ship)
- Find the 7 HK Components

  - Component #1 (Transistor): Outlaw’s Den in Tatooine.
  - Component #2 (Chassis): Taris – Sinking City
  - Component #3 (AI Regulator) Coruscant– Jedi Temple
  - Component #4 (Motivator/Arm) Dromund Kaas – Dark Temple Approach.
  - Component #5 (Power Core) Hoth – Glacial Fissure
  - Component #6 (Weapon Component) – False Emperor normal mode
  - Component #7 (Loyalty Chip) – Hardmode Maelstrom Prison/Foundry
- Complete mission:Lord of Agony (Heroic 2+) (automatically given when you go all the components)

Comment: @Frank I added the list of the things that have been done. I assume it is correct now?

Comment: That doesn't seem like it was that long.  Links are fine as supplemental information, but they shouldn't ever *be* the answer.  I've played SWTOR, but I don't recall getting HK-51, so I have no idea if it's correct or not.

Comment: HK-51 was added in a patch, I think 1.5 years ago. It isn't that long now, but you cannot do anything with this information. Where would you start mission 'Fatal Errors', how to get exactly all the components? Now it's just a sum-up of the things you have to do, not HOW. When someone wants to type out a whole guide here, it is too long, and not needed (because it is located in the link I added, and some other sites, but Dulfy rocks)

Comment: For it to be a proper answer here, yeah, you do have to type it out.  A summary is fine, but if someone gives all the steps, along with the how, I wouldn't be surprised to see it upvoted well past yours.

Comment: Hah, I tried to make it more detailed. Now he knows (and someone else in the future) how to start. Then it is just following the quest markers. You're right, it isn't that long :)

Comment: I like this answer as-is.  I agree that the "how" would be too much ... this process is quite long and huge pain.  If Dulfy ever goes down, there are other reliable guides.